# grabbing multiple types of tags in one jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

From http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events, "In all of our examples up until now, we've been passing anonymous functions as event handlers. However, you can create a function ahead of time and store it in a variable, then pass that variable as the event handler. This is useful if you want to use the same handler for different events or events on different elements."

```
$( 'li' ).on( 'click', handleClick );
$( 'h1' ).on( 'click', handleClick );
```

Is there a jquery to get all `li` and all `h1` elements in one liner? I interpret

```
$( 'h1 li' ).on( 'click', handleClick );
```

to mean "all `li` items inside of `h1` items"

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the selectors with commas.

```
$( 'h1, li' ).on( 'click', handleClick );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with:

```
$( 'h1, li' ).on( 'click', handleClick );
```

Here's the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).